# SSH permission denied (publickey.gssapi-with-mic) windows openssh

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, public-key, openssh

I am trying to SSH on my server using key but i am getting below error. I have windows machine. Also, I tried same from Cygwin and it connected!!. But , not able to do from command prompt. Error is below.

```
C:\Users\Rahul\.ssh>ssh username@example.com
Could not create directory '/home/Rahul/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'example.com ' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 67:b6:1e:8a:0f:26:db:75:8e:78:af:16:ae:be:49:c2.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/Rahul/.ssh/known_hosts). 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for 'C:/Users/Rahul/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: C:/Users/Rahul/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for key 'C:/Users/Rahul/.ssh/id_rsa':
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I have done various solution but not able to find solutions. Please help. THanks in advance

Comment: The real surprise is that `cygwin` lets you get away with it. Did you try `chmod 600 .ssh/id_rsa` from either `cygwin` or `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @merlin2011 Yes changed the permission. but still not able to connect via command prompt. I am out of solutions as I am able to connect it via cygwin . Actually need accesss via command prompt only. Hence, want solution.

Comment: `Could not create directory '/home/Rahul/.ssh'.` -> permissions there ?

Comment: @RahulM did it worked for u?